# Deciding Between Duplicate Records Based on Status and Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I am stuck on the best way to handle this. I am importing a file and building a data cleaning process. I have no choice but to accept this bad data. The file has some duplicate account numbers.

If the duplicate accountNum contains the same statusID, then I need to take the earliest date, but if the duplicate accountNum contains a different statusID then I need to take the latest date.

My thought is to separate the records into multiple temp tables and finally union the cleaned dups with the non dups... but that seems inefficient.

This is where I am starting:

```
SELECT accountNum,
       statusID,
       date,
       row_number() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY accountNum
                  ORDER BY date DESC 
           ) acct_dup_row_num,
       row_number() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY CONCAT(accountNum,statusID)
                  ORDER BY date ASC 
           ) status_dup_row_num    
INTO #tempTable1
FROM file
GROUP BY accountNum,
       statusID,
       date
HAVING COUNT(accountNum) > 1
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] i.e. enough sample data and desired results to fully illustrate the problem and all edge cases.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? One row per accountNum? If so, grouping by more than that column does not seem logical. This might be a variation on "first in group" logic; it would help to see some sample data provided as a script. I'll throw out that "earliest" means MIN, "latest" means MAX, and it seems you might be able to choose one to use based on the distinct status count.

Comment: `PARTITION BY CONCAT(accountNum,statusID)` why? Why not just `PARTITION BY accountNum, statusID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a derived table to count the distinct `statusID`. Based on the distinct count and order the [date] ASC or DESC.

```
select f.accountNum,
       f.statusID,
       f.[date],
       r = row_number() over (partition by f.accountNum
                                  order by case when s.cnt = 1 then f.[date] end asc,
                                           case when s.cnt > 1 then f.[date] end desc)
from   [file] f
       inner join
       (
           select accountNum, cnt = count(distinct statusID)
           from  [file]
           group by accountNum
       ) s  on f.accountNum = s.accountNum
```

What you want is the rows where `r = 1`